# In DDD are Value Object always at the leaves of a relationship tree?

Tags: domain-driven-design

If I have a photo album where each **Photo** can be commented on, Should the **Comments** be Entities or Value Object in these cases:

1. Comments can be added only anonymously (i.e. Comments have no relation to anything except the photo).
2. Comments can be added by registered users (i.e. there will be a relation between the Comment and User entity).
3. Comments can have comments (i.e. 1 user replying to another).

I think modeling a Comment as Value Object in the first case sounds reasonable as a Comment won't have any relationships with any other entities.

However, what about the 2nd and 3rd case? Does the need to identify which user Posted which Comment changes it from a Value Object into Entity?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two excellent posts on how to identify what is a [value object](http://lostechies.com/joeocampo/2007/04/23/a-discussion-on-domain-driven-design-value-objects/) and what is an [entity](http://lostechies.com/joeocampo/2007/04/15/a-discussion-on-domain-driven-design-entities/). I know that when I am stuck on which to use, I always give these articles a read.

To help you chose which one to use, think about the lifecycle of the **Comments** object.

Value Object

> "An object that represents a descriptive aspect of the domain with no conceptual identity is called a VALUE OBJECT. VALUE OBJECTS are instantiated to represent elements of the design that we care about only for what they are, not who or which they are." [Evans 2003]

Entity

> "An ENTITY is anything that has continuity through a life cycle and distinctions independent of attributes that are important to the application’s user." [Evans 2003]

After reading the articles, in particular the Value Objects one, and the story about identifying a child, ask yourself:

- Can a comment exist without a **Photo**??
- If all entities are unique, what would make a unique **Comment**?
- Value Objects are immutable, if I change a comment, how does that impact a Value Object **Comment**?

Answer (score 0):

Gibson's links are useful, but the short answer is:

> Comments are **not** value objects, in any of the listed scenarios.

You might model comments on a photo in Scenario 1 as an attribute of a photo containing a collection of strings, in which case you don't need an 'object' for them at all.

In the other two scenarios, the relationships require an identity for a comment, which makes Comment an entity.

Comment: Well, your last sentence is what I was hoping for someone to elaborate on. Does introducing a relationship to a Value Object promote it to an Entity? It would be really helpful if you expanded your answer by clarifying this point, plz.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on Steven's answer.

Comments are an **entity** in this case not value objects.

Two value objects are considered to be the same if their attributes can define their equality. In your case let say, If their are two comments with the exact same text in them and posted by the same user, Will those two comments be the same object? I think the answer is NO. It is possible for a user to add a new comment with the same text as the earlier comment.

Hence there must be some other identifier which distinguishes between these two comments other than their attributes making it an entity.

One other example would be if two different photos have similar text/user comments, Even then those comments should have two separate identities.

Hence ENTITY :)

Comment: This does not add anything new to the existing answers posted years ago.

Comment: @Snowman on Dec 14 Songo asked in comments `hoping for someone to elaborate on...` , So was just trying to elaborate on it, Thanks for your input

Comment: That was not clear from the review queue. I recommend editing your answer to reference Steven's answer and the comment below it.